# General Settings for Wordpress Subdomain

Tags: subdomains

I recently updated to the latest version of WP. One of my bloggers mentioned that the Preview link wasn't working for her anymore. I'm unsure whether the recent upgrade stopped it from working or if it was something else.

So, I did some research and someone suggested making sure that the WordPress URL and the Blog URL matched in the General Settings
http://wordpress.org/support/topic/post-preview-not-working-1

Mine did not...

They were denschool.com/blog and blog.denschool.com. So, I changed the WordPress URL to blog.denschool.com. My blog stopped loading correctly.

I changed it back in the database, but it's still not working.

How do I fix this?

Comment: *How* did the blog stop loading correctly?

Answer (score 0):

After changing the WordPress URL to blog.denschool.com, edit your .htaccess file.
If there is a line reading `RewriteBase /blog`, change it to `RewriteBase /`

Comment: Did my solution work for you?